# Why are these the only subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I saw in some notes the following:

The only subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are $\{0\}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$, and any set $L$ of the form $L =\{c\textbf{u} : c \in \mathbb{R}, \textbf{u} \neq \textbf{0}\}$ consisting of all scalar multiples of a nonzero vector $\textbf{u}$ (geometrically, $L$ is a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ through the origin $\textbf{0}$), and any
subset $P$ of the form $P = \{c\textbf{u} + d\textbf{v} : c, d \in \mathbb{R}, \textbf{u}, \textbf{v}\neq \textbf{0}, \textbf{v}\neq k\textbf{u}\}$ (this is a
span of the two linearly independent vectors $\textbf{u}$, $\textbf{v}$ and geometrically, $P$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ through the origin $\textbf{0}$).

$$$$

Could you explain to me why there cannot be also other subspaces?

Comment: That makes no sense, since $\mathbb R^2$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^3$, and therefore it is not a subspace.

Comment: There are infinite subsepaces of $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ of dimension two (and thus isomorphic with $\;\Bbb R^2\;$) , but none of them is $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ ...

Comment: So should it be that the only subspaces $\mathbb{R}^3$ are $\{0\}$, the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$, the straight lines throught the origin $0$ and the planes throught the origin $0$  ? @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that last comment of yours is correct.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Any subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ of dimension two is infinite. I guess you meant “infinitely many”.

Comment: @celtschk That's what "infinite subspace" is supposed to be understood to mean in this context when colloquial talk is used.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of a subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is *at most* $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^3 = 3.$

Since the dimension is a non-negative integer, this leaves only a few cases to work through.

- $\dim_\mathbb{R} V = 0$: Then $V=\{0\}.$
- $\dim_\mathbb{R} V = 1$: Then $V=L$ for one of your $L.$
- $\dim_\mathbb{R} V = 2$: Then $V=P$ for one of your $P.$
- $\dim_\mathbb{R} V = 3$: Then $V=\mathbb{R}^3.$

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that any subspace must contain the zero vector and the dimension is at most $3$ therefore we have only $4$ possibilities which are indeed $\{0\}$, lines through the origin, planes through the origin and $\mathbb R^3$ itself.